# Eclipse can't start on Linux: Java Fatal Error

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, debian

I installed eclipse standard luna on debian 7 by extracting the downloaded .tar.gz to /opt. When I try to run eclipse the splash screen starts up and disappears after 30 to 60 seconds. The terminal prints out the following error message:

```
(java:4821): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplayManager'

(java:4821): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `GdkDisplay'

(java:4821): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion `parent_type > 0' failed

(java:4821): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_once_init_leave: assertion `result != 0' failed

(java:4821): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_new: assertion `G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f92eb94c73f, pid=4821, tid=140269436700416
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0+0x5173f]  gdk_display_open+0x3f
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid4821.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I use oracles jdk 7 64 bit but ran into the same issue when I used openjdk 7 64bit.

I would be glad if somebody can help me with this issue.

Comment: The actual error log is in `/tmp/hs_err_pid4821.log`. Please look into that one, and if you still need help, please post the relevant lines *here*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running with -nosplash command line argument. This sometimes helps with gtk-java interaction.

Comment: It worked! The first time eclipse didn't show up complete though. So I killed it and started it with `-clean -nosplash` and it's starting up fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1- **Open a terminal** and **go** to your **eclipse folder**.

2- Run it with: ***./eclipse -nosplash***

Answer (score 1):

try adding
--launcher.GTK_version
 2
to eclipse.ini in the eclipse downloaded file

Comment: This allowed me to at least move a frameless Eclipse window

Answer (score 0):

`-nosplash` solved on Debian Stable 7.8 64 bit, Gnome 3.4.2 and Eclipse Luna (direct download) SR1a.

Comment: @mORA are you saying the problem causing the crash is solved with these versions (so an update might be an alternative fix) ? Or are you saying that the `-nosplash` workaround worked for you ?

Comment: `-nosplash` solves for this configuratione, but apparently, I cannot comment under the -nosplash answer since I don't have enough reputation to do so.